# Creating 3D surface plot using data from dictionaries

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having trouble figuring out how to convert my data into the X, Y, and Z axis for a a surface graph using matplotlib in python. The data is from a file that contains a list of 5 letter words and my program runs through the file and counts how may times each letter occurs in each position of a word. It is stored in 5 different dictionaries, one for each position. I'm thinking that I'll have to utilize the .keys() and .values() methods but I'm not positive.

I went into excel and made the graph to show an example of what I'm trying to do.

[image]
[image]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import string
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import numpy as np


#Creates a list of the alphabet in uppercase
alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase
letter_list = list(alphabet)

#Creates dictionary for lettercount. Keys = A-Z, Values = 0 
lettercount = {i: 0 for i in letter_list}

#Creates dictonaries for position frequency. Keys = A-Z, Values = 0 
position1_freq = {i: 0 for i in letter_list}
position2_freq = {i: 0 for i in letter_list}
position3_freq = {i: 0 for i in letter_list}
position4_freq = {i: 0 for i in letter_list}
position5_freq = {i: 0 for i in letter_list}


with open("answers.txt") as f:
    for i in f:
        i = i.rstrip()
        for word in i.split(" "):
            for letter in range(len(word)):
                #Iterates through alphabet
                for j in letter_list:
                    #If the letter in the word = j it will add 1 to lettercount and depending on what value the indicie letter is, 1 will be added to the proper position frequency
                    if word[letter] == j:
                        lettercount[j] += 1
                        if letter == 0:
                            position1_freq[j] += 1

                        if letter == 1:
                            position2_freq[j] += 1

                        if letter == 2:
                            position3_freq[j] += 1

                        if letter == 3:
                            position4_freq[j] += 1

                        if letter == 4:
                            position5_freq[j] += 1

#Sorts the lettercount dictionary to be high to low
sort_lettercount = sorted(lettercount.items(), key = lambda x: x[1], reverse= True)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection = '3d')



plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete example. I have used list and dictinary comprehensions since they quite common in python (good to get used to!) and the `Counter` class from the standard librariy. The code is therefore probably a little harder to read if you are not used to it, but the style is common in python, so I recommend learning it instead of using explicit for-loops. The `Counter` object is a kind of dictionary, so think of it as a dictionary. :)

I then use the `.values()`. function on the Counter to extract the result. I put it into a numpy array, since that is what matplotlib needs.

Finally, creating the 3d plot in matplotlib is a bit contrived. Matplotlib is not really good for categorical data (such as having letters on the X axis), nor for 3d plots with horizontal color bands (like in your excel example).

Anyways, here it is:

```py
from string import ascii_uppercase
from collections import Counter


# a dictionary with all ascii lettters as keys, and only zeros as values
zero_counts = {c:0 for c in ascii_uppercase}

with open('answers.txt') as f:
    # read the file into a list, remove trailing newlines and make sure all is uppercase
    lines = [line.strip().upper() for line in f.readlines()]

    # transpose the list, so that instead of having N 5-letter words, we now have 5 N-letter words
    list_of_chars_per_pos = zip(*lines)

    # for each of these 5 "words", count the number of occurrances of each letter
    # then add these occurences into a copy of the "zero" dictionary from before
    # so now we have 5 dictionaries holding the count for letter 0,1,2,3 and 4
    char_counts_per_pos = [zero_counts | Counter(chars)  for chars in list_of_chars_per_pos]


# matplotlib only works with numpy data structures, so lets change into that!
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(len(ascii_uppercase)) # the x axis will correspond to the letters
y = np.arange(5)                    # the y axis will be the positions
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)              # create 2D arrays with the X and Y coordinates

# here we extract the  data from the dictionaries using the .values() method
Z = np.array([list(dictionary.values()) for dictionary in char_counts_per_pos])

# now create the plot! create 3d axes on a new figure and draw the plot
# there is quite a bit of customization that can be done to the plot to make it look
# in whatever way you like.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator, FixedLocator
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
surf= ax.plot_surface(X=X,Y=Y,Z=Z)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(x))
ax.set_xticklabels(ascii_uppercase)
ax.set_box_aspect((26,5,5))
ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
ax.set_zlabel("Counts")
ax.set_ylabel("Position")

# finally, show the plot. :)
plt.show()
```

By running it on the following text file `answers.txt`

```
abbot
mince
grate
dodos
piggy
baron
party
```

I get the plot

[image: A 3d surface plot with the results]